# mysql query to count number of times each Id has been used

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table named `badges` with following structure:

```
UserId   Name  

5        reviewer
3        supporter
12       copy editor
5        master
3        master

.... and so on
```

here name is the name of a tag achieved by the UserId.

Now I want to count for each UserId how many number of tags he has achieved and display as output in decreasing order.

**Note**: the UserId and Name are not distinct, means a UserId can earn multiple tags and also multiple number of each tags.

I am having writing the mysql query for this.

Comment: Based on your note, you want `how many number of tags` or `how many distinct number of tags`?

Comment: Shows us what have you tried.

Comment: like I have mentioned in 'Note' above the tags can be multiple.Si, I want number of tags and not distinct number of tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most basic use of `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*)
FROM badges
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```